# Error con SqlTableDependency al hacer solicitudes cada segundo

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server-2014, sqltabledependency

me estoy migrando a SqlTableDependency para obtener notificaciones de los cambios en la base de datos en mi sistema web asp.net mvc. Anteriormente utilizaba SqlDependency para lograr obtener las notificaciones pero me pareció mas útil hacer esa migración.

El problema es un poco aleatario puesto que el sistema funciona salvo cuando un cliente elimina data y dispara el dependency y un segundo despues otro cliente hace un select a esa misma tabla.

Pienso que es porque se hacen las solicitudes bastante rápido pero esto no me pasaba cuando usaba sqldependency. Aquí el Error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The referenced entity 'INSERTED' was modified during DDL execution. Please retry the operation.'
```

Aquí mi codigo:

```
public class SqlMesas
{
    private CreatechContext db = new CreatechContext();

    public void Dependancy()
    {
        var cString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CreatechContext"].ConnectionString;
        SqlTableDependency<Mesa> dependency = new SqlTableDependency<Mesa>(cString, "Mesas");
        dependency.OnChanged += DataOnChange;
        dependency.Start();
    }

    private async void DataOnChange(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Mesa> e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.ChangeType != ChangeType.None)
            {
                MesasController controller = new MesasController();
                var data = await controller.GetMesasOrden();
                var hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<OrdenMeseroHub>();
                await hub.Clients.All.updateMesa(data);
                await hub.Clients.All.changeMesa("OK");
                Dependancy();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

¿Es posible solucionar esto? o continuo usando sqldependency puesto que este si lo hacia.

nota: aun no hago nada con la data que me regresa sqltabledependency porque aun lo estoy probando..